# how can i adjust gridview header ? asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which contains `EditItemTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` but `gridview` header not adjusting.How can i adjust my `gridview` header .
Here is my gridview [image: IMG]

Here is my aspx.cs code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       Enableviewstate="False" Width="1000px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333"  AllowPaging="true" Height="400px" DataKeyNames="User_ID" onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" >

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="User_ID" HeaderText="User_ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Name   " HeaderText="Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_NAME" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="User_Name" HeaderText="User_Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_USERNAME" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_username" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Email" HeaderText="Email">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_EMAIL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_email" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Password" HeaderText="Password">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_PASSWORD" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_password" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Password") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Date" HeaderText="Date">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TXT_DATE" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_Date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="header" BackColor="#7961da"
                                                            Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />       
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you need it adjusted?

Comment: No it's not i want `User_ID` move left blow numbers like id etc,and same for all header like `Name` blow name but header move to the right i want to adjust it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Maybe try creating an image with how you would like it to look. I'm guessing that a [GridView.HeaderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) may help.

Comment: its `th` i check using `inspectElement` how can i adjust `th` in gridview.my simple question is i want to move `left` gridview `th`

Comment: I want this `User_ID` header blow numbers like 1,2,3... and in `Name` blow name comes like Hameed,Ali etc.and same for next

Comment: My problem is solve @j.f. i want this kind of output [LINK](https://s32.postimg.org/g6e9t4hhx/Snap_2016_07_11_at_06_33_26.png). Blow answer worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alignment properties of the header for each field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
    ...
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you need more control on the output, you can also create a HeaderTemplate:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="..." />
        ...
    </HeaderTemplate>
    ...
</asp:TemplateField>
```